# Why krige function return all NA's values for the prediction when trying to interpolate a variable?

Tags: r, interpolation, kriging, gstat, stars

I am trying to build a map with kriging interpolation for a variable. When running the `krige` function the return is all `NA` values and the kriged map plot only one value. I couldn't find out why and I am a really basic user of these tools. Some older related answers mentioned the possibility that duplicate observations were causing this, but I checked and there are no duplicate records. I was able to build the variogram.

Here is the base map (shp file in a .zip file): http://www.filedropper.com/lpr000b16ae

Here is the data I want to interpolate: http://www.filedropper.com/yielddata

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(gstat)
library(stars)

## a) Defining the projection of the maps
proj_lambert <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

## b) Map Canada selected provinces.
canada.map <- st_read("C:[your path to]/lpr_000b16a_e/lpr_000b16a_e.shp") %>% 
  filter(PRNAME == "Manitoba" |
           PRNAME == "Alberta" |
           PRNAME == "Saskatchewan") %>%
  st_transform(proj_lambert )

## c) Data set
data.yield <- read_csv("C:[your path to]/yield.data.csv")
data.yield.coords <- data.yield %>% select(lat, long)
data.yield.data <- data.yield %>% select(av.yield)

#### Creating LAT LONG SpatialPoints
coordinates(data.yield.coords) = c("long", "lat")
proj4string(data.yield.coords) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # 4326 is the EPSG identifier of WGS84.

### Converting the LAT LONG to the lambert CRS shown above
lambert_data.yield.coords = spTransform(data.yield.coords, proj_lambert)
lambert_data.yield.coords = as.data.frame(lambert_data.yield.coords)

#### Adding the Type column back to the data frame, with the new polar coordinates
lambert_data = cbind(lambert_data.yield.coords, data.yield.data)

data.yield.sf <- st_as_sf(data.yield, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = proj_lambert)


## d) Variogram fit
v = variogram(av.yield~1, data.yield.sf)
plot(v, plot.numbers = TRUE)

v.m = fit.variogram(v, vgm("Sph", psill = 1, range = 5, nugget = 1))
plot(v, v.m, plot.numbers = FALSE)
```

This is the variogram:
[image]

And the rest of the code

```
## e) Building a empty grid
st_bbox(canada.map) %>%
  st_as_stars(dx = 1000) %>%
  st_set_crs(proj_lambert) %>%
  st_crop(canada.map) -> grd

## f) Kriging interpolation
k = krige(av.yield~1, data.yield.sf, grd, v.m)

## g) plotting all together
ggplot() + 
  geom_stars(data = k, aes(fill = var1.pred, x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_sf(data = canada.map, color = "gray", fill="transparent") +
  geom_point(data = lambert_data, aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

And here is the final map

[image]

Comment: @Kadir, thanks for the edits on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point:

```
data.yield.sf <- st_as_sf(data.yield,
        coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = proj_lambert)
```

the numbers in `data.yield$long` and `$lat` are lat-long degrees, but you are creating an `sf` object with a `crs` of `proj_lambert`. This won't change the numbers. You need to create this with a lat-long crs parameter, probably EPSG:4326, and then use `st_transform` to convert to `proj_lambert`.

I think what has happened is that you have computed the variogram on the lat-long degrees, and got a range of a few degrees, and then the interpolation has been done on `proj_lambert` and interpreted as metres. So your spatial scale is a few metres, and you can't see that on a national plot because all the spatial structure is less than a zillionth of a pixel, and it all looks flat at the data mean.

I'd investigate more but you've used `library(tidyverse)` which is a bad practice, since it pulls in hundreds of functions unnecessarily - please try and make minimal examples and if you do use package from the `tidyverse` bundle please include their individual `library` calls - here I think you are only using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`.

Comment: thanks so much for the response! it worked perfectly. And thanks also for the tip regarding `library(tidyverse)`. One last  question if you are able is how to interpret the range of the variogram fit now that I am using `proj_lambert`. Is the range still in meters?